# Limiting Maximum memory for code running in an AppDomain

Tags: c#, appdomain

I have a web application which allows user plugins to execute. As these plugins are untrusted I am loading them in a separate AppDomain with limited permissions. However, I can see that some user with malicious intent can still write some code in an indefinite loop which could hog memory. Is there a way to limit maximum memory that the code in an appdomain can consume? Say I want to limit it to 200MB, Is that possible?